# How to read data received by firestore get()

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I use vue and firestore.

I receive data through get().

```
onMounted(async () => {    
const forminfo = db.collection('forms').doc(route.params.id)
const doc = await forminfo.get()
content.value = doc.data().content
url.value = doc.data().url
}
```

And use `<p>{{content}} {{ url }} </p>` in the template.

However, this method does not reflect the line break when writing and does not make url into an image.

Comment: did you put the url in a img src?
<img :src='url'/>

Comment: @EdouardYonga Oh, I forgot something simple. Thank you.
But things like line breaks still don't work.

Comment: to go to a new line you can use normal <br> tag

Answer (score 0):

For the image to display from the given url use

```
<img :src='url'/>
```

for the line break add `<br>` where you want to create a new line

Comment: I mean the line break doesn't work with the data stored in the firestore.
Do I have to use white-space for line break to work?
Is there any other way than this way?